# jQuery's ready() function works in .jsp, but not in .jspx

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, jspx

This [jsp](/questions/tagged/jsp) works:

```jsp
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"> </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jqReady.js"> </script>
    </head>

    <body>

    <div id="hello">Empty</div>

    </body>
</html>
```

this [jspx](/questions/tagged/jspx) does not work:

```jspx
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<jsp:root xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" version="2.0">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"><!-- required for FF3 and Opera --><jsp:text> </jsp:text></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jqReady.js"><!-- required for FF3 and Opera --><jsp:text> </jsp:text></script>
    </head>

    <body>

    <div id="hello">Empty</div>

    </body>
    </html>
</jsp:root>
```

Both use the same `jqReady.js`:

```javascript
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#hello").text("Hello, world " + new Date());
    $("body").css("background-color", "grey");
});
```

In case of [jspx](/questions/tagged/jspx) the function passed to `ready()` is not called.

Using Firebug I have observed that `$.isReady`

- is `true` in case of [jsp](/questions/tagged/jsp)
- but it's `false` in case of [jspx](/questions/tagged/jspx)

I am using Iceweasel 3.5.16 (like Firefox 3.5.15), JBoss 7.1.1

Related questions/answers (I have already applied those recommendations):

- [Why is $(document).ready not firing for me?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1857072/2390083)
- [Script tag must have a content](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9435663/2390083)
- [Including JS files (JQuery) in JSPX files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8312011/2390083)
- [How soon will jQuery(document).ready be called?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2397534/2390083)

Comment: It doesn't make sense to assign a document ready handler inside an onload handler. Pick one or the other (preferably just the document ready). Have you tested that `init()` gets called in the jspx?

Comment: @nnnnnn `init()` was called in the JSPX (verified with `console.info()`). I have removed the onload handler, still same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution here: [HTML5 JSPX template](http://www.toly.nl/mmbase/1896/HTML5_jspx_template)

Using the template from that page, this JSPX works as expected:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<jsp:root xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" version="2.0">
    <jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="utf-8" />
    <jsp:output omit-xml-declaration="true" />
    <jsp:output doctype-root-element="HTML"
        doctype-system="about:legacy-compat" />

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"><!-- required for FF3 and Opera --><jsp:text> </jsp:text></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jqReady.js"><!-- required for FF3 and Opera --><jsp:text> </jsp:text></script>
    </head>

    <body>

    <div id="hello">Empty</div>

    </body>
    </html>
</jsp:root>
```